# The probability that after repeated random drawing from an urn, all balls left in the urn will be red

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

#### Problem

An urn contains $p$ red and $q$ green balls. Balls are drawn one by one till balls left in the urn are all red. Prove that the probability of this event is $\dfrac {p}{p+q}$. Please note that you are told that balls of same colour are left in the urn and you need to find the probability that these remaining balls are red.

#### Progress

Okay, so first of all, we note that it is pretty confusing that whether balls of same colour are considered identical or different is not known. I proceeded by assuming the balls are all distinct.

We need a minimum of $q$ turns and a maximum of $p+q-2$ turns.
When we have $q$ turns, the $q$ green balls are permuted in $q!$ ways. Probability = $\dfrac {q!}{(p+q)P(q)}$ since in our sample space we need to get arrangement of $q$ balls from $p+q$ balls.

When we have $q+1$ turns, select the green ball which will be in $q+1$th place in ${q\choose 1}$ ways, then select one red ball in ${p\choose 1}$ ways, then arrange the $q-1$ green balls and $1$ red ball in $q!$ ways, so probability is $$\dfrac { {q\choose  1} { p\choose 1}(q!)}{(p+q)P(q+1)}$$
We go on like this upto $p+q-2$ trials and add up all this, but this is not coming out as $p/(p+q)$

Comment: I tried many ways, nothing seems to work. But all my methods seem correct to me, at least.

Comment: Put some of what you've tried into your question: that'll give us a better sense of your progress and where things may be going wrong.

Comment: Are you familiar with recurrence equations?

Comment: What 'event' exactly? Do you mean the event that it comes that far that after some drawing there are no green balls in the urn anymore while there are still balls in the urn?

Comment: I am familiar with recurrence relations. Can you please show a method to apply such relations here? That is, a complete answer, please?

Comment: Edited. And @drhab, yes, you go on taking out balls until there is no green ball left in the urn. But, take care that there are AT LEAST two balls in the urn finally, if I have interpreted the question correctly. Because otherwise, I don't think "same red balls" makes sense.

Comment: @AnonymousMaths how do you infere that at least TWO red balls are left in the urn? The way I see the problem you only need at least ONE red ball left in the urn.

Comment: If you require two red balls to be left in the urn, then by a similar reasoning as the one I made or the one drhab did, the chance would be $\frac{p(p-1)}{(p+q)(p+q-1)}$ wich is not $\frac{p}{p+q}$

Comment: You can type binomial coefficients as `${n \choose k}$` or `$\binom{n}{k}$`. Also note that the displayed math `$$  $$` is an option.

Comment: What if $p=1$? then the probability of at least two remaining red balls is zero but $\frac{p}{p+q}$ is not.

Comment: Reading this question literally, you seem to be asking:  What is the probability that balls will be drawn from the container until all the remaining ones are red?  Mathematics is not powerful enough to answer that question.

Answer (score 3):

This problem needs a change in notation. $p$ and $q$ look like probabilities and hard to remember which is red and which is green. So, we have a box with $r$ red balls and $g$ green balls. We remove balls one at a time (at random) until there is one ball left. Show that the probability that the last ball in the box is red is $r/(r+g).$

Let the pair $(R_k,G_k)$ be the number of red and green balls remaining in the box after  draw $k.$ The pair is an absorbing Markov chain. The absorbing states are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1).$ The initial state is $(R_0,G_0)=(r,g).$ Let $p(i,j)$ be the probability that the last ball in the box is red starting from the state $(i,j).$

Now condition on the result of the first ball drawn:
$$p(r,g)=\frac r{r+g}p(r-1,g)+\frac{g}{r+g}p(r,g-1)   $$

Clearly, $p(i,0)=1$ for $i\ge 1$ and $p(0,j)=0$ for $j\ge 1.$ So this gives the result for $1$ ball in the box. Now, by induction suppose we know $p(i,j)=i/(i+j)$ when we have $n=i+j$ balls in the box, $1\le i\le n.$ The case $n=1$ holds. Using this on the RHS of the recurrence relation above,
$$ \frac{r}{r+g}\frac {r-1}{r-1+g}+\frac{g}{r+g}\frac{r}{r+g-1} $$
which equals $ \frac{r}{r+g}$ completing the induction by showing the formula is correct for a box with ${n+1}$ balls.

Comment: no!! please see the problem carefully. At least two balls of the same color are remaining, not one ball is remaining.

Answer (score 1):

The condition means that if you continue extracting balls, the last one will be red.

There are $\displaystyle p+q\choose\displaystyle  p$ ways to order all the balls. If we fix the last one red, we can order the rest of them in $\displaystyle p+q-1 \choose  \displaystyle p-1$ ways. The probability is then:

$$\frac{p+q-1 \choose p -1}{p+q \choose p} = \frac{\frac{(p+q-1)!}{(p-1)!q!}}{\frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}} =\frac{\frac{(p+q-1)!}{(p-1)!}}{\frac{(p+q)·(p+q-1)!}{p·(p-1)!}} =  \frac{p}{p+q}$$

Comment: Actually, after clarification, you are taking out balls till you have balls of same colour left. Find the probability that these remaining balls are red. You have to prove that this probability is p/(p+q)

Comment: @AnonymousMaths yes, that's what I did. The condition that states that you remove all the balls at random until the remaining ones are red is equivalent as to remove all the balls and that the last one is red. Those two things are equivalent.

Comment: But how is that equivalent? :( Sorry but this apparently means you are implying that 2nd last green, last red = 2nd last red, last red, which is not the case right!

Comment: @AnonymousMaths You don't need the penultimate ball to be red or green. If the last ball is red it means that at some point, all the remaining balls in the urn were red.

Comment: This is exactly what I am not getting :( So sorry for that. How does this imply that the remaining balls in the urn were red? :( How can the possibility that there is a mixture of red and green balls be ruled out?

Comment: Well, you had both of them until only red remained. Even if the penultimate ball was green, the last ball is red, so when you remove the green one, you'd only have red balls left (only one).

Comment: 1st paragraph: excellent observation. How about 2nd paragraph change to: "The last remaining ball is a randomly selected ball from the original set of p+q balls, and its prob of being red is therefore p/(p+q). QED."

Comment: @greggo Yeah, I thought of it after I wrote the answer. It looks totally simpler that way! drhab wrote that answer as I was considering rewritting it, so I decided to leave my solution as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I formulate two problems here and give an answer to both of them.

It is up to you to sort out wich of the problems you are dealing with.

Personally I think it is problem 1. This because of its nice answer
$\frac{p}{p+q}$.

Draw all $n:=p+q$ balls and let $C_{i}\in\left\{ R,G\right\} $ denote
the colour of the $i$th ball drawn.

Problem1:

To find is the probalitity of the event that after drawing less than
$n$ balls we land in a situation in which all balls left in the urn
are red.

This event is exactly the event $\left\{ C_{n}=R\right\} $ and $P\left\{ C_{n}=R\right\} =\frac{p}{p+q}$

Problem2:

To find is: $P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R=C_{n}\mid C_{n-1}=C_{n}\right\} $
i.e. the probability that the last two balls drawn were red under
the condition that they had the same colour.

We find:

$P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R=C_{n}\right\} =P\left\{ C_{n}=R|C_{n-1}=R\right\} P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R\right\} =\frac{p-1}{p+q-1}\frac{p}{p+q}$

$P\left\{ C_{n-1}=G=C_{n}\right\} =P\left\{ C_{n}=G|C_{n-1}=G\right\} P\left\{ C_{n-1}=G\right\} =\frac{q-1}{p+q-1}\frac{q}{p+q}$

$P\left\{ C_{n-1}=C_{n}\right\} =P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R=C_{n}\right\} +P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R=C_{n}\right\} =\frac{\left(p-1\right)p+\left(q-1\right)q}{\left(p+q-1\right)\left(p+q\right)}$

So $P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R=C_{n}\mid C_{n-1}=C_{n}\right\} =\frac{P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R=C_{n}\wedge C_{n-1}=C_{n}\right\} }{P\left\{ C_{n-1}=C_{n}\right\} }=\frac{P\left\{ C_{n-1}=R=C_{n}\right\} }{P\left\{ C_{n-1}=C_{n}\right\} }=\frac{\left(p-1\right)p}{\left(p-1\right)p+\left(q-1\right)q}$

Answer (score 1):

> An urn contains $p$  red and $q$  green balls. Balls are drawn one by one till balls left in the urn are all red. Prove that the probability of this event is $p/(p+q)$  . Please note that you are told that balls of same colour are left in the urn and you need to find the probability that these remaining balls are red.

No, just look to the complement.  This event can only **not** happen if all balls are drawn and the last one turns out to be green.  Of all the $p+q$ balls that could be the last one drawn, just $q$ of them are green.  $$\begin{align}P(\text{Event}) & = 1-P(\text{Complement}) \\[1ex] & = 1-\frac{q}{p+q} \\[1ex] & = \frac{p}{p+q}\end{align}$$